# Filtering and deleting entries in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table looks like below

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
1    John   asd@asd.com
2    Sam    asd@asd.com
3    Tom    bcd@asd.com
4    Bob    bob@asd.com
5    Tom    bcd@asd.com
6    Tom    bcd@asd.com
7    ash    ash@asd.com
8    Bob    bob@asd.com
```

Now i want to write a query, which should detect the duplicate key value pairs. i.e like below and it should delete them from SQL table.

```
5    Tom    bcd@asd.com
6    Tom    bcd@asd.com
8    Bob    bob@asd.com
```

Finally if i query my table it should look like this

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
1    John   asd@asd.com
2    Sam    asd@asd.com
3    Tom    bcd@asd.com
4    Bob    bob@asd.com
5    ash    ash@asd.com
```

Comment: Your desired result is incorrect. I assume you want to delete 5 and keep 7 since 5 was Tom not ash.

Comment: Hi, the result should be not more-than a row should have same name & email.

Comment: Yes, and we have already provided solutions ;) What i wanted to say is, your desired result is incorrect since the last row contains `ash` with `ID=5`, but `ash` is `ID=7` instead. Don't modify your primary keys (if that's what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [ID], [NAME], [EMAIL],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [NAME], [EMAIL] ORDER BY ID ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1;
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31c93/1)</kbd>

But your desired result is incorrect. I assume you want to delete 5 and keep 7 (5 was Tom not ash).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for both MySQL and SQL Server:

```
delete  YourTable
where   id not in
        (
        select  min(id)
        from    YourTable
        group by
                name
        ,       email
        )
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dcf4/3/0)

Comment: i'm using sql server 2008, will this work. i'm poor in sql :(